# Change the pointer of an object array

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a bit new to pointer

In my program I have defined a class "Record" and two array

```
Record book[10];

do{
    Record tempBook[10];
    // ... Some sorting command

    // Set "book" to the content of "tempBook" here

}while()
```

Can someone suggest what I should do to set book to the content of tempBook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you've to understand the difference between [automatic and free-store objects](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm) and their lifetimes to understand the below explanation.

#### Objects to Objects

```
std::copy(book, book + 10, tempBook);
// if you compiler supports C++11, then
// std::copy(std::cbegin(book), std::cend(book), std::begin(tempBook));
```

This will copy all the contents of `book`s to `tempBook`s.

#### Pointers to objects

If you want a set of pointers to point to books, then you've to declare `tempBook` as pointers of `Record` data type and not as objects.

```
Record books[10];
// later
Record *tempBooks[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   tempBooks[i] = &books[i];
}
```

#### Pointers to Pointers

If you want to create 10 books on stack and then copy them to another array (in stack), then you can use `std::copy` as above. If you want to create objects in free store (using new/delete), then create them and make any number of pointers point to those anonymous objects thus:

```
Record *books = new Record[10];
// later
Record *tempBooks = books;
```

#### Smart Pointers

However, I'd suggest you to use smart pointers that C++11 provides for better memory handling and to avoid memory leaks; use shared pointers.

```
#include <memory>
std::shared_ptr<Record> spBooks[10];
spBooks[0] = make_shared<Record>(/*pass constructor arguments*/);

// later
std::shared_ptr<Record> spTempBooks[10];
std::copy(spBooks, spBooks + 10, spTempBooks);
```

**Even better is to use `std::vector`s.** Low-level memory handling, however fascinating it may seem, leads to hard to find bugs; it's prudent to leave it to container classes to handle it for you.

Comment: I think he wants the other way around.

Comment: @leemes: Yes, I felt so too; added them

Comment: `std::end(spBooks)` is better than `spBooks + 10`

Comment: @Jarod42: Agreed; I didn't write it so, since the question wasn't tagged `C++11`. However, smart pointers are important enough that I included it anyways.

Comment: @legends2k, It is generally a good advice to always assume the OP runs the latest stable version *unless* specified otherwise.

Comment: @Jarod42: Added it as a comment now

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I will stick to choice Obj to Obj one at the moment and try to digest the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can do looping to assign the values from tempBook to book. For example

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    book[i].property = tempBook[i].property;
}
```

Comment: or just assign `Record` instances, providing they're copy-constructible

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: assignment will use assignment (i.e. `Record& operator=(const Record&)`), not copy construction.

Answer (score 0):

Define one copy c'tor and assign one object to other wihout any hassles.

```
      class Record {

         public:
               Record(const Record& rec) {
                    //do your assignment from rec to this pointer
               } 
      };
```

If you define one like this then,

```
     do{
         Record tempBook[10];
         // ... Some sorting command
         for (size_t i=0; i<10; i++)  //Define array size in macro
         {
                tempBook[i]=book[i];
         }
     }while()
```

Here tempBook has life with-in the while loop. what ever modification you are doing with the tempBook will not reflect the book objects. My advice is to use vector in place of array of objects.

So for setting book content to tempBook you can use the above mentioned method.